# Dynamic Youtube Video With jQuery & jSON

Tags: jquery, json, youtube

So I have a jSON object coming back and I want to pull the thumbnails from the object, add click event, once clicked it builds the SWF player based on the jSON object. I'm having a hard time basically "binding" the thumbnail to the SWF. So when you click on this thumbnail build this SWF.

Here is a JSFiddle of pulling the thumbnails out. I'm not sure if I am setting this up right. Not sure if setting up the click event needs to be in the for loop.

[jsfiddle.net/MW9HR/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/MW9HR/2/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should **not** be in the loop, since you are (*correctly*) using the live method.

You are, however, passing the swf data incorrectly.

it should be `$('.thumbnail').live('click', {swf:$swf}, function(e){`

Now you can access it from inside the handler with `e.data.swf`

You also use the [`.die()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/die) method to unbind previous live click handlers (*in case your code is ran more than once*), so

```
$('.thumbnail').die('click').live('click', {swf:$swf}, function(e){
```

---

I also, altered your code to add an identifier on each thumbnail so you can easily map them to the array of videos.

```
$videos += '<li class="video"><img class="thumbnail" data-videoid="'+$i+'" src="' + $thumbnail + '" alt="' +$title + '" /></li>';
```

You can retrieve this `videoid` when you click on the element with the [`.data()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data) method as `$(this).data('videoid')`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/JfqtK/